# Sqoop on Windows - "not a valid DFS filename"

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to use Sqoop 1.4.5 on Windows and feel like I'm
*almost* there.  But I've hit one stumbling block I can't
yet figure out and am hoping someone can point me in
the right direction.

Right now, I can get Sqoop to run and it gets as far as generating
the Java class for the table I'm importing, and then
starts trying to push jar files to the jar file cache.  And this
is where the trouble comes in.   Since I'm on Windows
the path to those jars is something like

```
e:\win-hadoop\hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT\sqoop\lib\db2jcc4.jar
```

and the like.  This of course results in errors like this:

```
15/05/18 17:36:21 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Pathname /E:/win-hadoop/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/sqoop/lib/db2jcc4.jar from hdfs://10.1.115.231:9000/E:/win-hadoop/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/sqoop/lib/db2jcc4.jar is not a valid DFS filename.
```

Any thoughts on how to get around that?  This happens whether I'm running the sqoop.cmd
file in a regular Windows cmd window, or running the unix script in a Cygwin shell.

(Also, if anybody is wondering, this Hadoop 3 business is because I built Hadoop from
source to get the Windows support and building HEAD just gives you stuff
labeled Hadoop 3.  I don't *think* that's part of the problem, but feel free to convince
me otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but solved it by changing the file format !! check the format of mapred-site file(in /etc/hadoop/). It should be in the xml format ... mapred-site.xml NOT mapred-site.xml.template ! remove that .template!  hope it helps.